# How to implement an ExecutorService to execute tasks on a rotation-basis?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using [java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with [fixed thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) to execute list of tasks.  My list of tasks will typically be around 80 - 150 and I've limited the number of threads running at any time to 10 as shown below:

```
ExecutorService threadPoolService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for ( Runnable task : myTasks ) 
{     
    threadPoolService.submit(task); 
}
```

My use case demands that even the completed task should be re-submitted again to the *ExecutorService* but it should be executed/taken again only when all the *already* submitted tasks are serviced/completed.  That is basically, the tasks submitted should be executed on a rotation-basis.  Hence, there will not be either `threadPoolService.shutdown()` or `threadPoolService.shutdownNow()` call in this case.

My question is, how do I implement *ExecutorService* servicing rotation-basis tasks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ThreadPoolExecutor provides an extension point for afterExecution where you can put the job back at the end of the queue.

```
public class TaskRepeatingThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public TaskRepeatingThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        this.submit(r);
    }
}
```

You'll have to do a little more work of course to instantiate it yourself without the help of `ExecutorService`'s handy factory method, but the constructors are simple enough to grok.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion and letting me know the existence of `ThreadPoolExecutor` class.  I've a question here, what/how/why do I need to pass `BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue` to the constructor.  In case of `ExecutorService`, I used to submit all my tasks like this `threadPoolService.submit(task)`.  Am not able to understand about this `BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue`.  Hope you can make me understand this.

Comment: Just read about `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` and thought of updating it back here.  `BlockingQueue` is basically used to hold the work/task which is being sent to the executor when all the threads in the pool are busy executing the tasks.

Comment: I am not sure this technique works, afterExecute is called with FutureTask(Runnable - Wrapper around the actual task) which has internal state which keeps track of completion status. If re submitted it just returns without executing actual task.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is more related to the implementation of the *work queue* used for the instance of `ExecutorService`. So, I'd suggest:

1. First choose an implementation of [`java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) ([an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642760/can-we-use-blockingqueue-to-implement-circular-buffer)) that provides a *circular queue* functionality. **NOTE**, the reason `BlockingQueue` has been chosen is that to *wait* until the next task is provided to queue; so, in case of *circular + blocking* queue, you should be careful how to provide the same behavior and functionality.
2. Instead of using `Executors.new...` to create a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` use a [direct constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) such as

> `public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit,  BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)`

This way, unless you command the executor to `shutdown`, it will try to fetch the next task from the queue for execution from its *work queue* which is a *circular* container for tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution which completely uses functionality existing in the standard library concurrency utils. It uses a `CyclicBarrier` with a task decorator class and a barrier action which re-submits all tasks:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Rotation {

    private static final class RotationDecorator implements Runnable {
        private final Runnable          task;
        private final CyclicBarrier barrier;


        RotationDecorator( Runnable task, CyclicBarrier barrier ) {
            this.task = task;
            this.barrier = barrier;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.task.run();
            try {
                this.barrier.await();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                ; // Consider better exception handling
            } catch(BrokenBarrierException e) {
                ; // Consider better exception handling
            }
        }
    }


    public void startRotation( List<Runnable> tasks ) {
        final ExecutorService threadPoolService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
        final List<Runnable> rotatingTasks = new ArrayList<Runnable>( tasks.size() );
        final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier( tasks.size(), new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Rotation.this.enqueueTasks( threadPoolService, rotatingTasks );
            }
        } );
        for(Runnable task : tasks) {
            rotatingTasks.add( new RotationDecorator( task, barrier ) );
        }
        this.enqueueTasks( threadPoolService, rotatingTasks );
    }


    private void enqueueTasks( ExecutorService service, List<Runnable> tasks ) {
        for(Runnable task : tasks) {
            service.submit( task );
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check that all the tasks have been executed and resubmit them once it is the case, like this for example:

```
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Runnable task : myTasks) {
        futures.add(threadPoolService.submit(task));
    }
    //wait until completion of all tasks
    for (Future f : futures) {
        f.get();
    }
    //restart
    ......
```

**EDIT**
It seems you want to resubmit a task as soon as it gets completed. You could use an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) which enables you to retrieve tasks as and when they get executed, - see below a simple example with 2 tasks that get resubmitted a few times as soon as they are completed. Sample output:

> Task 1 submitted pool-1-thread-1
>   Task 2 submitted pool-1-thread-2
>   Task 1 completed pool-1-thread-1
>   Task 1 submitted pool-1-thread-3
>   Task 2 completed pool-1-thread-2
>   Task 1 completed pool-1-thread-3
>   Task 2 submitted pool-1-thread-4
>   Task 1 submitted pool-1-thread-5
>   Task 1 completed pool-1-thread-5
>   Task 2 completed pool-1-thread-4

```
public class Test1 {

    public final ConcurrentMap<String, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public final AtomicInteger retries = new AtomicInteger();
    public final Object lock = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int count = 0;
        List<Runnable> myTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        myTasks.add(getRunnable(1));
        myTasks.add(getRunnable(2));
        ExecutorService threadPoolService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        CompletionService<Runnable> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Runnable>(threadPoolService);
        for (Runnable task : myTasks) {
            ecs.submit(task, task);
        }
        //wait until completion of all tasks
        while(count++ < 3) {
            Runnable task = ecs.take().get();
            ecs.submit(task, task);
        }
        threadPoolService.shutdown();
    }

    private static Runnable getRunnable(final int i) {
        return new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Task " + i + " submitted " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500 * i);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted");
                }
                System.out.println("Task " + i + " completed " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  ");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I need to resubmit every individual tasks  as and when it is getting completed, but not to `wait until completion of all tasks`.  Any ideas/comment?