# How to configure the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool properties correctly?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, executorservice

I configured a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, but the outcome is different than I expected. It the following behaviour correct? And how could it be explained?

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    int core = 1;
    int max = 1;
    int queue = 2;

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor bean = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    bean.setCorePoolSize(core);
    bean.setMaxPoolSize(max);
    bean.setQueueCapacity(queue);
    bean.setKeepAliveSeconds(60);
    return bean;
}


@Scheduled(initialDelay = 5000, fixedDelay = 10000)
public void init() {
    int nthreads = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
        async.run(i);
}


@Service
public class MyAsync {
    @Async("taskExecutor")
    public void run(int i) {
        Sysout("running: " + i);
    }
}
```

Who can explain the following result for different pool configurations:

- core = 1, max = 1, queue = 2: RejectedExecutionException thrown (why, because I just created 1 thread?)
- core = 1, max = 2, queue = 2: RejectedExecutionException thrown (again: why? two threads should be allowed, and I'm just starting `nthreads=1`.)
- core = 1, max = 2, queue = 5: nothing happens. No sysout is printed (why?)
- core = 1, max = 2, queue = 5, nthreads = 3: nothing happens
- core = 1, max = 2, queue = 5, nthreads = 4: now this one executes, but starts throwing RejectedExecutionException
- core = 2, max = 2, queue = 5, nthreads = 4: again, nothing happens

I don't get this behaviour of the async executor.

My goal is as follows: create an `Executor` that has 1-2 threads running (depending on the load). Tasks should be queued up to 5 threads. And if any thread is in the queue for more than 60 seconds, they should time out and be removed if not executed.

Comment: rejection only happens on submit, you can't reject a task after it was queued (and therefore accepted) for 60 seconds

Comment: yes I can, what else would the `keepAlive` timeout be for?

Comment: killing idle threads, core..max http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379314/how-does-keep-alive-work-with-threadpoolexecutor

Comment: Oh ok, so the keepAlive just defines the timout for threads between max-core. I misunderstood that, thanks.